# Replicating strict Relational Database through Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am fairly new to the ORM logic. Most of it has been discovered through Spring Boot's JPA. Now I wanted to replicate the idea of normalisation to ORM as well. My intention was to realise the following ER diagram :

```
                           / \ 
                          /   \
+---------+      m       /     \        n       +---------+
| Student |-------------: Takes :---------------| Courses |
+---------+              \     /                +---------+
                          \   /
                           \ /
```

Thus, I created 3 entities, whose definitions were as follows:

```
// Course.java
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int credits;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

```
// Student.java
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int semester;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

```
// Takes.java
@Entity
public class Takes {

    @Id
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Course course;
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Student student;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

However I failed to achieve what I wanted. My first point of failure was the fact that, I cannot simply make use of the `id` of both the entities (`Student` & `Course`) directly into `Takes` as foreign keys. Instead, I have to create entire objects of both the entities over here. And the second point of failure was the fact that after performing the mapping, deletion of an instance of `Takes` lead to deletion of the instances of corresponding `Students`. What I expected was something in reverse to this.

So, with the above observation as the context, is there a way to actually realise what I set to do above, or is it something not feasible/doable in Spring Boot's JPA?

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve.
Student and course have manytomany relationship.  That should be done using "@manytomany " annotation

Comment: In a relational database, I would have created 3 tables : Student, Course & Takes. I was trying to adopt the same idea to Spring Boot JPA.

Comment: by the approach of "@manytomany" - the third table (Takes) is created by default by JPA, if you have set auto create to true. anyway see the tutorial link given in the answer, you will understand

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to achieve is manytomany relationship. Student can have  many as Courses (m) and Courses can have many as students (n).
So your Entities should be like below

```
// Course.java
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int credits;
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Student> students;
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

// Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int semester;
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Course> courses;
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

You can follow this for more details
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Surely it does the job, however it wasn't what I wanted. Over here, what I want is basically an approach to manually create my own 'Takes' table and to be able map it to both the entities.

Comment: if you want to retain and solve your two reported issues?
you have to add below two things
1. create field of type "Takes" in Student and Course classes
2. Annotate that with "@OneToMany" 
In this way you make it a bidirectional relationship and it should work as you expected

Comment: @Argon your present implementation is unidirectional, which means Takes - owns both students and course , that is the reason JPA deletes the entities when Owning entity Takes - is deleted.

Comment: So, does it imply that if the implementation of 'Takes' is made bidirectional, then I'll achieve what I want to?